# Which server stack should I choose to for my Emberjs project on AppFog

Tags: ember.js

I want to use AppFog beta services in order to test them, and develop a web application with Emberjs framework. So, I wonder which server stack should I use on AppFog for my project ?
Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick any server stack you are familiar with, if it doesn't matter, I'd pick PHP which uses a standard Apache stack. If you want to try Sinatra or Node, you can pick those too, they will all support Emberjs